# Logging in with REST API

Tags: rest, api, web-services, authentication

I am building a user account service which handles basic log in/out and view/edit account profile etc.

They enter their email and password which I need to authenticate. Please do not comment on any security issues (API not public etc) thanks!

The service has a RESTful API so was considering how best I design the API. I have some options...

```
GET api/accounts?email=x&password=y

Returns an array of Accounts of size 1 if valid (or 0 if not)
```

or

```
POST api/login_requests (where body contains email/passwword)

Returns an Account if valid (or Not Found if not)
```

I'm thinking the latter but not sure this is really restful (I don't really have login_request resources - so seems a bit procedural).

Thoughts? Maybe there are other options/standard approaches?

Answer (score 0):

GET, in HTTP protocol communication term, try to 'read' information . And this itself have possible states value that can be handler, (200, 201, 400, 404) .
If the case is such static response, (like 1 or 0 if not) , would be a clever option directly resolve with the protocol (it why it exist ) .

Comment: Both are valid in this scenario as far as I know, but GET seems more RESTful

Comment: Yes, both are valid in practical terms, but there is a 'no respecting' communication 'intention'.  
RestFul is an arquitecture that is 'mounted' throught http protocol .
I see it, like a lower leverl ssue .

Comment: Hi Franco, if neither of my suggested approached 'respected' communication 'intention' then I'm interested in how you would approach this log in requirement?